# What was the Democratic vote increase from 2012 to 2020 in Texas?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, texas

I want to see an image of raw Democratic vote increase from 2012 to 2020 for president. I want it to by % and not just vote numbers so it's not biased towards larger counties. Biggest decrease (smallest increase) should be goldest and largest dark brown with a gradient. I want it with the same color scheme as the [Cook Political Report](https://cookpolitical.com/2020-national-popular-vote-tracker) article. State level image for *all* votes from '16 to '20 for president as an example:

[image: Nationwide vote increase over 2016, all]

Texas saw the biggest margin swing towards Democrats from 2012 to 2020 out of any predominantly non Mormon state, narrowly beating Massachusetts. Contrary to Massachusetts, most of the percentage swing came in 2016.

It also had the second biggest raw Democrat vote percentage increase from 2012 to 2020 out of any predominantly non Mormon state. The colors was just a guideline. It's not something I require, I just want it to look similar and I like that color.

Comment: This isn't that hard to make - try doing it in R

Comment: You're probably getting a lot of downvotes because of the extremely demanding tone (insisting on a color scheme??)

Comment: It's like you're dictating a mandatory homework for us! If you want it, DO IT YOURSELF.

Answer (score 5):

See below.

[image]

Sources:

- [2012 Texas county election results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_United_States_presidential_election_in_Texas);
- [2020 Texas county election results](https://www.politico.com/2020-election/results/texas/);
- [Texas boundaries](https://www.depts.ttu.edu/geospatial/center/TexasGISData.html).